# Using Shiny.onInputChange

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am using an entirely html ui and have my `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` in the head of my document and am passing it data using `session$sendCustomMessage` and that works wonderfully!  I send a query to Google BigQuery and have gotten it to authorize and everything using the javascript, and it brings back an array with my query to the Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler section of my code (I know it does because I can print it to the browser console using `console.log`), but even with a `Shiny.onInputChange` command, my data is not being sent back to my `server.R` for processing.  Will this command not work inside the `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` function?  Is there another thing I could use to send it back?

Thanks so much for all your help this week!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  Shiny.onInputChange will not work within customMessageHandler.